# Find a continuous surjection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $Y = \{(x, y) : 0 < x \leq 1, y = \sin (1/x)\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-writing

I'm looking for $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow Y$, where $f$ is a continuous surjection in the context of the following problem:

-Show the subspace $Y = \{(x, y) : 0 < x \leq 1, y = \sin (1/x)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

My solution strategy:

I want to apply the theorem that says: Let $f:(X, \tau)\rightarrow (Y,\tau_1)$ be a surjective, continuous function from one topological space to another.  Then, if $X$ is connected, so is $Y$.

Question:  Will the following function work:

$$f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             (x, \sin(1/x)),  & 0 < x \leq 1\\
             \\ \emptyset , &\mbox{ otherwise,i.e., not defined} 
            \\
             \end{array}\right.$$

Clearly, this is a surjection since each element in $Y$ has an inverse image in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

But I'm unsure about how to rigorously establish that $f$ is continuous by means of the general topological definition of a continuous function as a map from open sets to open sets.

Intuitively, I can envisage a correspondence between open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose intersection with the infinite vertical strip $(0,1]\times(-\infty, \infty)$ is mapped vertically to a connected portion of the curve $y=\sin(1/x)$, and the inverse map where connected portions of the curve are mapped to the infinite vertical strip that covers its x-values.  But this seems vague and hand-wavy.

Am I on the right track?

[P.S.: Apologies for one more question relating to the Topologist's Sine Curve, but I believe this one is different in its focus on continuity rather than connectedness:

Citation:  S. Morris "Topology without Tears", 5.2.6 (i)]

Comment: What you defined is not a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to Y$. $f$ is only defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, then let's just use the subspace (0,1]×(−∞,∞) as the domain and skip the piecewise portion.

Comment: That's fine, and what you need to do next is to show $f$ is continuous. Do you know the fact that restriction of codomain preserves continuity? That is, if $f$ is a continuous map into $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the image of $f$ is contained in $Y$, then $f$ is continuous as a map into $Y$.

Comment: If you really wanted an answer to the title question, you could use something like $(x, y) \mapsto (\frac{1}{1+x^2}, \sin(1+x^2))$ or $(x, y) \mapsto e^{-x^2}, \sin(e^{x^2}))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier to just take the domain to be $(0,1]$.  Hopefully, the surjection (bijection in fact) to $Y$ is self-evident.  Crucially, in your problem you don't have to worry about $x=0$, which is the real thorn for the Topologist's sine curve.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see.  I think I'm making things more difficult than they have to be.  Are you saying, since the x-axis interval (0,1] x {0} is a subset of R^2, then that interval itself can be made into a subspace which I can then use as my domain to bijectively map the points (x,0) to (x, sin(1/x))?

Comment: Yes, basically.  But I don't think it's that essential that (0,1] is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected in general.

Comment: Ok, I agree.  Now that I re-read the theorem I want to apply, I was incorrectly thinking that since Y was a subset of R^2, then X also had to be.  But that's a false assumption -- (0,1] with the normal Euclidean topology is fine for X with no further details.